# How return template from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have async fnction and 2 block of template, function called in render
But instead of template I get objectPromise
Why it happens and how fix it?

```js
 async renderTabsDependOnStatusAccess() {
    if (true) {
        return this.renderTabsAfterLogin()
    } else {
        return this.renderTabsBeforeLogin()
    }
}

render() {
  return (
      <div class="navigation">
          ${this.renderTabsDependOnStatusAccess()}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Generally, you need to `await` the resolved value of a Promise (which is what an async function returns). However, it looks like there's no need for your function here to be async. Is there more to your implementation than you have shared?

Comment: Whatever React components you want to render, you could store as state somehow, and then render that state, rather than rendering whatever that function returns (it returns a promise, so React can't render that)